# Drop nearly-duplicate rows based on value in one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with taxa at different levels, and data from multiple sources for some of the taxa. Here's the structure of the data:

```
species <- c("species1", "species1", "species2", NA, NA, NA, "species3")
genus <- c("genus1", "genus1", "genus1", "genus2", "genus2", "genus3", "genus4")
value <- c(1:7)
source <- c("source1", "source2", "source1", "source1", "source2", "source2", "source3")
data <- cbind.data.frame(species, genus, value, source)
```

When a taxon has two rows, one with data from each source, I want to drop the rows where the value in the source column is source1. When a taxon only appears once in the table, I want to keep it in, regardless of the value in the source column. So for example, for the taxon that is species1, genus1, I would want to keep the row where the value = 2, and for the taxon that with NA in the species column and genus = genus2, I would want to keep the row where value = 5.

So the final output table would look like this:

```
species    genus    value    source
species1   genus1   2        source2
species2   genus1   3        source1
NA         genus2   5        source2
NA         genus3   6        source2
species3   genus4   7        source3
```

I can think of hacky ways to do this, but was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it. Apologies if this question has already been addressed-- I wasn't sure what search terms to use to find the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include what the desired output table might look like?  "A picture is worth a thousand words"

Comment: Is this example representative of the larger data set? In particular, are the only sources either source1 or source2?

Comment: @lebelinoz I added an example of the output table. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @neilfws there are also some taxa with source3. I'll add a row to make that clearer.

Comment: So could taxa come from all 3 sources? Or from sources 1 and 3, or 2 and 3? And if so, which should be retained?

Comment: @neilfws there aren't any cases where the taxa come from all three sources. There are two different types of taxa (one with sources from 1 and/or 2, and the other from source 3). So you could essentially ignore the taxa that come from source3 for this question

Comment: OK. I think your example output should have `source2` for the case `value = 6`, based on your example input.

Comment: @neilfws, you're right! Sorry about that. I updated the output table in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the data and logic correctly:

- taxa (genus + species) may occur once or twice in the table
- where they occur once, the source may be 1, 2 or 3
- where they occur twice, the source may be 1 or 2
- in the case where they occur twice, source 2 should be retained

So one approach is to group by genus + species, count the rows per group and retain source 2 where the count is 2, or retain all sources where the count is 1:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(genus, species) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(source == paste0("source", n) | n == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-n)

   species  genus value  source
    <fctr> <fctr> <int>  <fctr>
1 species1 genus1     2 source2
2 species2 genus1     3 source1
3     <NA> genus2     5 source2
4     <NA> genus3     6 source2
5 species3 genus4     7 source3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try spreading the data:

```
library(tidyr)
spread.data = spread(data, key = "source", value = "value")
```

Result:

```
   species  genus source1 source2
1 species1 genus1       1       2
2 species2 genus1       3      NA
3     <NA> genus2       4       5
4     <NA> genus3      NA       6
```

Then it's a case of using some kind of `ifelse` manipulation.  Here's how I'd do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
spread.data %>% mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(source2), source1, source2))
```

With three sources, the modification is to nest a couple of `ifelse` statements based on your preferred sources...